# Alterar saída format json no rails?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho uma API que está com os dados no seguinte formato:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "vehicle": "350",
    "code": "350",
    "delivery_date": "2019-07-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "created_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "vehicle": "364",
    "code": "364",
    "delivery_date": "2019-07-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "created_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "vehicle": "1305",
    "code": "1305",
    "delivery_date": "2019-07-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "created_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-07T17:00:37.000Z"
},
]
```

A questão é que devido (creio eu) aos " [ ] " não consigo realizar a pesquisa 
url/api/loads/list/**1**

logo como faço para alterar essa saída?

```
@loads = Load.all
        render json: @loads, status: 200
```

Atualmente é isso que tenho.

Comment: A saida está assim pq o Load.all retorna uma lista de "load", se vc quer retornar apenas um elemento tem q fazer um find `        render json: Load.find(params[:id]), status: 200`

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue fazer isso. Você criou uma saída para o index das suas listas, que mostra todas. Se você quiser criar um endpoint para mostrar um item específico, 
crie uma rota show.

```
def show
  @load = Load.find(params[:id])
  render json: @load, status: 200
end

namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :loads, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

Lembrando que esse api e v1 são apenas boas práticas de APIs, a única coisa necessária para funcionar é criar um endpoint show.